# GitPython equivalent to git diff HEAD

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I have:

- 5 modified but unstaged files
- 2 modified and staged files
- thus 7 modified files.

I know the following GitPython equivalents to git commands:

- `repo.index.diff(None)` gives the same result as `git diff` - 5 modified but unstaged files
- `repo.index.diff('HEAD')` surprisingly gives the same result as `git diff --staged` - 2 modified and staged files

Thus my question is, what is GitPython equivalent to `git diff HEAD`?

P.S. I can merge results of `repo.index.diff(None)` and `repo.index.diff('HEAD')` to get the desired output but it looks quite stupid...

Comment: The Git equivalent is of course to run `git diff HEAD`. There's no general-Python answer either, really, as you're looking for something built into the GitPython library. So the only appropriate tag here is [tag:gitpython]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
repo = git.Repo('path/to/my/repo')
print(repo.git.diff(repo.commit()))
```

This showed the diff for both staged and unstaged modifications.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me using [`GitPython`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html).

```py
repo = git.Repo(".")
output = repo.index.diff("HEAD")
```